# What is the correct way to compare a Django queryset with a JSON dataset?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-queryset

I have a Django unit test that creates a temporary database and applies some changes to it.

I also have a separate JSON file with a version of the data that represents how the data should look after the changes.

What is the most recommended way to compare the results of the functions on the test data to the JSON dataset?

I have tried using assertQuerysetEqual() but it doesn't seem to be working. When I do

```
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        Api.objects.all(),
        [repr(record) for record in delete_check_data if record['model'] ==  'fim_app.api'],
        ordered=False
    )
```

the outcome is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidmaness/development/fim_db/fim_app/tests/delete_test.py", line 49, in test_delete
    ordered=False
  File "/Users/davidmaness/development/fim_db/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 965, in assertQuerysetEqual
    return self.assertEqual(Counter(items), Counter(values), msg=msg)
AssertionError: Counter({'<Api: 2>': 1, '<Api: 3>': 1, '<Api: 4>': 1}) != Counter({"{'model': 'fim_app.api', 'pk': 1, 'field[474 chars]: 1})
```

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to compare the serialized representation of the QuerySet to the JSON data rather than the QuerySet itself. For instance, if you're using [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to serialize your instances, then you could use Django's `assertEquals()` to perform the comparison as follows:

```
    from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
    from my_app.models import MyModel
    from my_app.serializers import MyModelSerializer
    
    # perform a HTTP GET request on the API endpoint
    api_response = self.client.get('/api/myendpoint/')
    
    # serialize the model instances
    serializer = MyModelSerializer(MyModel.objects.all(), many=True)

    # convert the serialized data to JSON
    result_expected = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)

    # compare the JSON data returned to what is expected
    self.assertEquals(api_response.content, result_expected)
```

Comment: This is the best way to go. Serialize both sets such that they are in a more comparable state and then compare them.